# Unknown class CFieldsTemplates for field templates

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

I have used jomsocial with jomsocial profile type.But when i try to regiter it gives me "Unknown class CFieldsProfiletypes for field profiletypes. " error.

Profiletype is in group.

And in backene i can not be able to see the field type as profiletype.

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the versions you are using? Are they current? What steps have you taken to debug this issue?

Comment: i have used jomsocial 3.2 ,jomsocial profiletype 4.0.16 and joomla 3.3.6.And also i tried to add fieldtype  profiletype in customize profile in jomsocial but it did not worked for me.Thanks for replying .

Answer (score 0):

In Backend -> Components -> JomSocial -> Configuration -> Customize profiles, check if all fields are associated with any group.

This errors often pops up if fields are not associated with any groups.